# How do I set-up Rest API to the Mongodb installation on my Mac Pro

Tags: mongodb, google-app-engine

I'm developing a Google Apps Script application and I want to have a MongoDB backend to the application. Currently I am using a Mongolab sandbox account and successfully interacting with the collection on the Mongolabs servers.  The performance is very good and the support at Mongolabs has been excellent.

That said, long-term I've decided to host my own Mongodb on my Mac Pro that is currently running Yosemite. I already have Mongodb installed and its working fine.

**My Question**: How do I use (install/configure/establish) a Rest API (or other means) to connect with my locally installed Mongodb database.  I have spent a couple hours on 10gen's site and on Google trying to figure it out, but I have not quite gotten there.   Does anyone have experience doing this or something similar that might be able to share your experience or at least refer me to a good resource.

Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: The top result for the obvious search term is [this page in the official documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/) which lists several methods. MongoDB does support a [very basic](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#simple-rest-interface) built in interface, but this is really not for real application usage. You can look at running one of the suggested servers there locally that mimics near enough the Mongolab API or otherwise wrap your services to the underlying dependency. We don't do recommendations as answers here.

Comment: @NeilLunn I saw the official docs on the mongodb site. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to read through that and come away with a clear course of action, thus my question.

Comment: The "clear answer" is "choose one" or "build one". If I would "recommend" (which is off-topic for discussion here) anything it would be "build one". At some point your "script application" is going to want some real "brains" on the server rather than basic CRUD, which is essentially all any of the listed solutions really provide.

Comment: @NeilLunn - Thanks for the input. You make a good point about the application wanting some brains at some point.